# Can't make rails 3 logger work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I'm using tail -f to watch the log/development.log file (production and test don't exists, so it's the right enviroment), but the only thing being written into that file are sql queries generated by rails db:create/migrate, etc.

A simple logger.debug 'hello!' in the controller doesn't work. I'm calling it before the line that's bringing a rails error. <strike>Is it possible that the logger doesn't write the errors right away, and fails if something happen later?</strike> I tried with a clean response like return render :text => 'bla'

I added config.log_level = :debug to the development.rb file.

I also executed 'chmod 2777 log -R' just in case

Any ideas?

ps. I'm using ubuntu 11, ruby enterprise and passenger/nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logger is fine, but tail -f isn't working for some reason. I'm so angry right now. See you in serverfault